# Render filter hook on specific div on post content page on front end

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I have created a table of content filter hook which matched the header tag and put it in the table of content div. The `div` renders before the `the_content` filter. But, I am trying to render it in a specific `div`.

The part of single.php where I want to render the table of content is as below:

```
<div class="container programs">
        <div class="my-4">
            <h2 class="title-underline"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="overview-nav">
            <div>
                <h3>Overview</h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
           //Part where table of content should render. Unfortunately the below code does not work
            <?php

                if(function_exists("add_table_of_content")){
                    add_table_of_content();
                }

            ?>
        </div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
```

The function for table of content is as below:

```
//Table of Content
function get_toc($content) {
    $headings = get_headings($content);
    if(count($headings)>0){
      ob_start();
      echo "<div class='table-of-contents'>";
      echo "<div class='heading'>";
      echo toc_print($headings, 0);
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return "";
  }

  function single_heading($heading, $flags){

    if($heading['tag'] == 2 && $flags[0]){
    }
    elseif($heading['tag'] == 3 && $flags[1]){
    }
    elseif($heading['tag'] == 4 && $flags[2]){
    }
    elseif($heading['tag'] == 5 && $flags[3]){
    }
    elseif($heading['tag'] == 6 && $flags[4]){
    }
    else{
      return "";
    }
    return "<li>"."<a href=#".str_replace(" ", "_", $heading['name']).">".$heading['name']."</a>"."</li>";
  }

  function toc_print( $a, $depth) {
    $flags = array(
      get_theme_mod("toc_heading2", 1),
      get_theme_mod("toc_heading3", 1),
      get_theme_mod("toc_heading4", 1),
      get_theme_mod("toc_heading5", 1),
      get_theme_mod("toc_heading6", 1),
    );

    $r = "<ul>";
    $depth = 2;
    $depth_save = 2;
    foreach($a as $key => $tag){
        if($tag['tag']==$depth){
            $r = $r.single_heading($tag, $flags);
        }
        elseif($tag['tag']>$depth){
            $r = $r.str_repeat("<li><ul>", $tag['tag']-$depth).single_heading($tag, $flags);
            $depth = $tag['tag'];
        }
        else{
            $r = $r.str_repeat("</ul></li>", $depth - $tag['tag']).single_heading($tag, $flags);
            $depth = $tag['tag'];

        }
    }
    $r = $r.str_repeat("</ul>", $depth-$depth_save+1);
    return $r;
 }

  function get_headings($content) {
    $headings = array();
    preg_match_all("/<h([1-6])(.*)>(.*)<\/h[1-6]>/", $content, $matches);
    
    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
      $headings[$i]["tag"] = $matches[1][$i];

      $att_string = $matches[2][$i];
      preg_match("/id=\"([^\"]*)\"/", $att_string , $id_matches);

      if(count($id_matches)>1){
        $headings[$i]["id"] = $id_matches[1];
      }
      
      $att_string = $matches[2][$i];
      preg_match_all("/class=\"([^\"]*)\"/", $att_string , $class_matches);
      for($j = 0; $j < count($class_matches[1]); $j++) {
        $headings[$i]["classes"][] = $class_matches[1][$j];
      }
      $headings[$i]["name"] = $matches[3][$i];
    }
    return $headings;
  }

  function headingwraps( $matches ) {

    $headings = array();
  
    if(count($matches)>2){
      foreach($matches[2] as $key => $heading){
        $h = "<h".$matches[1][$key]." ";
        $h = $h." ".$heading." ";
        $h = $h.">";
        $h = $h."<span class='toc-span' id='".str_replace(" ", "_", $matches[3][$key])."'></span>";
        $h = $h.$matches[3][$key];
        $h = $h."<span class='toc-span-end' ></span>";
        $h = $h."</h".$matches[1][$key].">";
        array_push($headings, $h);
      }
      return $headings;
    }

    return $headings;
  }

  function add_table_of_content($content) {
    if (get_post_type()!="post") return $content;

    $result = preg_match_all("/<h([1-6])(.*)>(.*)<\/h[1-6]>/", $content, $matches);
    $headingwrapped = headingwraps($matches);

    $paragraphs = explode("</p>", $content);
    $paragraphs_count = count($paragraphs);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $paragraphs_count; $i++) {
        if ($i === 0) {
            $new_content .= get_toc($content);
        }
            $new_content .= $paragraphs[$i] . "</p>";
    }
    foreach($headingwrapped as $key => $headingrep){
        $new_content = str_replace($matches[0][$key], $headingrep, $new_content);
    }
    return $new_content;

  }

add_filter('the_content', 'add_table_of_content');
```

I tried to use add_shortcode filter hook to create a shortcode and put that shortcode to that specific div.

```
<?php echo do_shortocode("add_tale_of_content"); ?>
```

This did not work.

**Updated code using shortcode**

```
//in function.php
add_shortcode('the_content', 'add_table_of_content');

//to render in front end
<?php do_shortcode('add_table_of_content'); ?>
```

Comment: You write "Unfortunately the below code does not work" and "This did not work.". What did not work in detail? Was anything shown?

Comment: It displays the table of content in the ```the_content``` filter. But I want to display the table of content in ```div``` of ```overview-nav``` class. it does not work to render outside the ```the_content```.

Comment: you wrote `do_shortocode("add_tale_of_content");` which is missing a b in table, it should likely be `do_shortocode("add_table_of_content");`

Comment: Got error ```Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function do_shortocode()```. used ```add_shotcode('the_content', 'add_table_of_content');``` and ```<?php do_shortocode("add_table_of_content"); ?>``` to render in ```overview-nav```.

Comment: you've to take care what you write,. there are always typos in your commands: in `add_shotcode` is the r missing, it should be `add_shortcode`. and in `do_shortocode()` is an o too much

Comment: typo mistakes are here in comments. But in PHP file it's correct. Still there is no output on front end. there is no error either.

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) your usage of `do_shortcode` is wrong. The parameters are 1) $content (string) 2) $ignore_html (bool)

Comment: So I corrected the format to ```<?php echo do_shortcode('[add_table_of_content]'); ?>``` but it only echo out ```[add_table_of_content]``` instead of the table of content.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use shortcode? You can call the function directly with the below changes:

```
<div class="container programs">
    <div class="my-4">
        <h2 class="title-underline"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="overview-nav">
        <div>
            <h3>Overview</h3>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
            //Part where table of content should render.
            $content = get_the_content();
            if (get_post_type() =="post"){
                echo get_toc($content);
            }
            ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $content; // This line was changed too ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the name of the shortcode and not the name of the function.

So if you define your shortcode:

```
//in function.php
add_shortcode('name_of_your_shortcode', 'add_table_of_content');

//to render in front end
<?php do_shortcode('name_of_your_shortcode'); ?>
```